# Xamarin form Exception at base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); Vs 2019. application for Android 10.0. API 29 was working fine for API 28

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[Excepetion at base.OnCreate() VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtn1e.jpg)

I am getting exception on base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); it is for android 10.0 API 29. it was working fine for API 28. I added some references and sdk for API 29 and after that its giving this exception. I am new and trying develop my first app in xamarin form for android only.

Thanks.

Comment: Delete the binand obj folder and try to clean and rebuild the project. If this does not work, restart the VS to try again.

Comment: its still giving same exception. :(

Comment: Try to upgrade your SDK and Xamarin.Froms. Have you checked it on another device with API29?